# Using tablesorter, how can I format a column AFTER the sort is applied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, tablesorter

In my Rails 3 app, I have a view with a table where I'm using the [tablesorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

One of the columns in the table is timestamps, formatted in time ago as words. For example:

```
1 minute ago
19 days ago
1 month ago
never
```

etc.

The problem is, when I sort this using tablesorter, it doesn't sort as I want it to (by time), but instead alphabetically, so what I end up with is:

```
1 minute ago
1 month ago
19 days ago
never
```

However, I'm just not sure how to do this. What I really want is to represent each column as a timestamp, have tablesorter apply the sort, and THEN format it using time ago in words. But I just can't seem to get this to work.

Any one have any suggestions or can point me to any examples of how I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is many years after the fact, but with my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), you can use the [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/dates) date parser to sort various "plain language" times ([demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-dates.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would fake it with some hidden data like this example: http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/dLqdC/1/

so you have somehting like

```
<tr> 
    <td><span class="hidden">1</span>today</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td><span class="hidden">2</span>tomorrow</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td><span class="hidden">0</span>yesterday</td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: This worked for separating the time from minutes/days/months/etc, but it doesn't solve the number problem: "42 minutes" is still above "6 minutes" - Any ideas?